# Shrink swap partition significantly on SSD (Linux)

Tags: partitioning, ssd, gparted, swap

I allocated a huge amount of swap space (127G) for a system with 128G ram. I want to reclaim most of that space and make it available to my Linux file system. This is what GParted currently looks like:

[image: Gparted disk partitions]

The Resize/Move command is currently greyed out. I want to reduce the swap space to 4G or 8G (or some amount that is deemed desirable -- comments on that?) and add it to the filesystem mounted on `/`. Can I do it without losing data?

Comment: Run `swapoff`, delete the swap partition,  resize existing `/` partition, recreate new (smaller) swap partition and then run `swapon`?

Comment: And this doesn't lose data?

Comment: no, it pulls stuff back into memory.. It would be best to get a crap disk to run as your swap file not use the ssd

Comment: Thanks, I shrunk my swap space to 8G, didn't even have to reboot the computer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to reboot from a LiveCD/USB/Network and make the changes from there.

Alternatively, you can plug the SSD into another computer as a secondary drive and make the changes from the other computer's OS.

**Otherwise, if you want to do this from within your running OS:**

You can use the `swapoff` and `swapon` commands (probably requiring `sudo`) to disable and later re-enable swap. With swap disabled you should be able to move/resize the swap partition without a problem. With 128GB of RAM you may not even get any benefit from swap at all.

I doubt that you can safely resize your boot partition while you are using it, however you could create a new partition in the empty space and mount it somewhere for extra space.

Comment: I do not want to grow the boot partition, but the partition mounted on `/`.

Comment: The `/` partition is what I meant by 'boot partition'. The system is almost certainly going to need to read from it during a resize, which could lead to disaster. Perhaps it is possible to boot into a fallback shell and copy all the binaries you need into a ramdisk and maybe remount the root to the ramdisk. Could be fun but what if something goes wrong?

Comment: I already did it... whoops. Everything seems to be OK. Wouldn't gparted be smart about it and make sure the system doesn't read when it's doing the resize?